# Connecting in Dubai on different airlines

Tags: india, layovers, dubai, air-india, qantas

We are traveling to London via Dubai (DXB). We are using different airlines. Air India from Mumbai to DXB and, after a 6 hour layover in Dubai, we fly Quantas to London.

Am I correct that we will have to collect our bags, go through Immigration, and check in for the next flight. Would we need a visa to transit in Dubai?

How long does all this take? Do we have to change terminals?

Comment: What citizenship do you hold? You booked two separate tickets for this?

Comment: US Citizen. Yes two seperate tickets first one on Air India (expedia) and second with American Airlines.

Answer (score 2):

[At DXB Quantas departs from T3, and Air India arrives at T1](http://www.dubaiairports.ae/before-you-fly/which-terminal/check-by-airline), so you'd have to transfer between terminals. AFAIR there is airside transfer at DXB, so if you have no luggage, and check in online/come to a staffed transfer desk, you could proceed directly. If you have luggage, you'd have to re-checkin and go through immigration; there is a free shuttle between terminals. As a US citizen you don't need a visa. Immigration at DXB is usually fast, and with 6 hours layover you'll even have time to briefly visit the city if you want to.

Comment: You can just ask the dnata transit desk to re-check your luggage. They offer this service for a fee.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to collect your bags. Just walk upto any dnata transit service desk and show them your tags. They will collect and re-check your bags; assuming you have boarding passes for your next trip.

If you do not have boarding passes, you will have to enter the country. As a US citizen, you can use the e-gate and don't need a visa. Simply go through the e-gate procedure, immediately after the e-gate is a security check point for hand luggage and after that there are the luggage carousels.

Collect your bags from T1 and then take the free shuttle to T3; or (depending on how much luggage you have) you can take the Red line metro.

At T3, you need to check-in for your next flight, go again through immigration and security controls and then you'll be in the vast transit area of terminal 3.

Note that depending on your flight - you may have to take the train to the F gates (which are for the A380). This adds about 15 minutes to your total foot journey time.

If traveling with minimal luggage, then entire process is easily finished in under 2 hours (counting for queues at immigration, the various lifts you have to go through, collecting and waiting for your bags, waiting for the queue for the shuttle, and check-in).

Rushed, you can do it in 1 hour but you'll be exhausted by the time you check-in again - there is a *lot* of running around you have to do. Especially in T3